# Easy way to hold/release jobs by job array task id in slurm

Tags: slurm

I have a bunch of job arrays that are running right now (SLURM).

For example, `2552376_1`, `2552376_10`, `2552376_20`, `2552376_80`, `2552377_1`, `2552377_10`, `2552377_20`, `2552377_80` and so on.

Currently, I am interested in that which end with `_1`.

Is there any way to hold all others without specifying job ids (because I have several hundreds of them)? 
The following command works for holding all the jobs:

`squeue -r -t PD -u $USER -o "scontrol hold %i" | tail -n +2 | sh`

For releasing the one with needed id I use

`squeue -r -u $USER -o "scontrol release %i" | tail -n +2 | grep "_1$" | sh`

which picks correct jobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mass update of jobs can be done by abusing the output formatting of `squeue`:

Hold all your pending jobs:

```
squeue -r -t PD -u $USER -o "scontrol hold %i" | sh
```

then release all your jobs ending in `_1`

```
squeue -r -t PD -u $USER -o "scontrol release %i" | grep "_1$" | sh
```

First run the commands without the `| sh` part to make sure it is working the way intended.

Note the `-r` option to display  one  job  array  element per line.

Comment: this seems to work: `squeue -r -t PD -u $USER -o "scontrol hold %i" | sh`  `squeue -r -u $USER -o "scontrol release %i" | grep "_1$" | sh`